# searchText and findText not working for android solo tests when there is a message notification?

Tags: android

Using Android2.1 when I try to use solo's searchText or findText it isn't able to find text in text notifications created with makeToast, has anyone ran into this problem before and know a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new Robotium version 1.8.0, that problem does not exist anymore. It can be downloaded from:

http://code.google.com/p/robotium/downloads/list

/Renas